# In Neo4j (using Lucene index) how can I find what a Node has been indexed under?

Tags: neo4j, lucene, luke

For a given index and key, I can look up Nodes using (Cypher):

```
START n=node:index('key:*')
RETURN n
```

Or using (Embedded Java):

```
Index<Node> index = .....
IndexHits<Node> hits = index.query(key, query);
Iterator<Node> itr = hits.iterator();
```

What I'm looking for is a way to do this in reverse; to find key/value pairs for which a given Node has been indexed. Something like:

```
Map<String, Object> pairs = index.getKeyValuePairs(node);
```

The only tool I've been able to find which goes in this direction is [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/), but this is a desktop Java app, making it tricky to use on indexes which are on a server.

The reason I'm interested in this is because I've got a large neo4j dataset where I've mis-indexed some Nodes. Now I can't find them without using a wildcard index query which is too imprecise and requires iteration of the returned `IndexHits`, or using a Cypher query `WHERE` clause, which is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Neo4j 1.9 you can't. In Neo4j 2.0, you can get the Labels and Indexes on a node, e.g.

```
CREATE n:Person{name:'Jim'}
```

Make an index

```
CREATE INDEX on :Person(name)
```

List labels

```
MATCH n
RETURN LABELS(n)
```

Comment: OK, that'll be it then. I'm still on 1.8.2.